# Methods of fetching data while updating the ui in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

So this question bothered me for a while because i can't seem to find out an easy, convenient and natural way to update ui while fetching data from external locations (Webserver).

I will sketch my scenario :

I got a webserver, which serves JSONArray's and JSONObject's. It always returns this because i don't like nullpointers. I tried to write a class which extends `AsyncTask`. I succeeded in doing this and it looks like this :

```
public class Server extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object>{

        private String fetch_url;
        private String return_type;
        private Activity ct;

        public Server() {
        }

        public Server(Activity ct) {
            this.ct = ct;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {


        }


        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(String... url) {
            this.fetch_url = url[0];
            this.return_type = url[1];

            if(return_type.equals("json_object")) {
                return urlToJsonObject(this.fetch_url);
            } else {
                return urlToJsonArray(this.fetch_url);
            } 



        }




        private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
           /*
            * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
            * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
            * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
            * and returned as String.
            */

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

           String line = null;
           try {
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   sb.append(line + "\n");
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } finally {
               try {
                   is.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

           return sb.toString();
        }

    protected JSONObject urlToJsonObject(String url) {
        JSONObject arr = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);

                // A Simple JSONArray Creation
                arr = new JSONObject(result);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();


            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arr;
    }

    protected JSONArray urlToJsonArray(String url) {
        JSONArray arr = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);

                // A Simple JSONArray Creation
                arr = new JSONArray(result);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();


            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arr;
    }

    }
```

After the data came in, i transform it to my own models with getters and setters. Then i want to update my ui with these results, but for some reason i always receive nullpointers.

For example :

- I got an GridLayout which i want to fill with multiple PhotoAlbums.
- First i am fetching those records from my webserver.
- Then processing each album.
- Then if an individual Album gets added to the GridLayout it needs to update. And not all at once while blocking ui.

What is a nice central way of getting data from external sources and updating ui while it is loading? Can somebody point me to techniques, tutorials, methods, insights, etc. I am very curious about this.

Comment: you can use onPostExecute(param) to update ui. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. You can also use lazy list or Univaersal image loader if you are downloading images from server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a constructor already so you can use that to accept a reference to your `Activity` that needs to be updated or a reference to `Views`. Pass a reference of your `Activity` when you create the `AsyncTask` then adjust your constructor to accept that reference. Then you can use that to call `Activity` methods inside `onPostExecute()` or `onProgressUpdate()` that will update the `UI` when finished.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859299/getter-method-of-asynctask-that-run-from-other-file/16859550#16859550) for a better example

`AsyncTask`s [getStatus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus()) may be helpful to you also if you need to know when it is finished